# Skip decimal numbers from values with "thousands" mark in a DT::datatable()

Tags: r, dt

In the `DT::datatable()` of my `shiny` app below I have found how to add "thousands" mark )(.) in my table but I want to get rid of the decimals numbers.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    dataTableOutput("table")
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  iris<-iris[,1:4]*100000
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({ 
    datatable(iris) %>%
      formatCurrency(columns = c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width","Petal.Length","Petal.Width"), currency = "", interval = 3, mark = ".") %>%
      formatStyle(
        columns = c("Sepal.Length")
       ) })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Just add `digits=0` to the `formatCurrency()` call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `digits=0` to the `formatCurrency()`.